# what is the longest period for a transection to be confirm?

Tags: blockchain.info, confirmations

Today my friend  transferred bitcoins to my account and up till now there still 0/no confirmation.so how long is actually the period for the transection to be confirm? it is almost 8hours ad still no even single confirmation,plus I cannot even transferred my bitcoin to my friends. PLEASE HELP ME.

I've tried to search the solution but still dont get it.

this is the transection link:
3757f5a11b2c1af3b4f58f6d922496327aa6cba242772adad4cd928f2a736a9d

Comment: The transactions has also been confirmed, so I'm closing this.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the transaction details on [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/tx/3757f5a11b2c1af3b4f58f6d922496327aa6cba242772adad4cd928f2a736a9d), it looks like part of the problem is that this transaction spends an input which is unconfirmed.  If/when the input gets confirmed, and if everything else with the transaction is kosher, it's probably just a matter of time before the transaction is confirmed.